# Reactivity of input in nested modules

Tags: r, shiny, module, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to do a shiny App (NavbarPage) with n=4 different tabPanels. All Panels have will have (nearly) the same structure, so I decided to use modules for that. To make the code reusable for other apps I put all my variables into global.R.

My Problem:
I want to have an option panel on the top of each site. Some options are the same for each tabPanel, some differ. In my "optionServer" module I want to store all inputs into a global reactiveValues Variable "optionSel". Actually, it is easily possible to access the input-variable(s) via renderPrint() [means it should not be a typing error] but I can find no way to store the input value as an reactive(input$...) etc..

Please see my code and thank you very much for your help

#global.R

```
library(shiny)
source('module/functmodul.R')


    label<-c("Label1", "Label2","Label3", "Label4")
    tabs<-c("tab1","tab2","tab3", "tab4")
    
    optionset<-list(c('opt11'=1,'opt12'=2,'opt13'=3),
      c('opt21'=1,'opt22'=2,'opt23'=3),
      c(TRUE,FALSE),
      c('opt41'=1, 'opt42'=2, 'opt43'=3,'opt44'=4))
    option<-data.frame('id'=c('id11', 'id12','id13', 'id14'),
                       'label'=c("choice1: ", "choice2: ", "choice3", "choice4"), 
                       'defval'=c(1,1,FALSE,1))
    #checkboxGroupInput=1,radioButtons=2,checkboxInput=3
    opttab<-data.frame(
      c(1,2,3,0),
      c(2,0,0,0),
      c(0,0,0,0),
      c(0,0,0,1)
    )
    optionSel<-reactiveValues()
```

#ui.R

```
shinyUI(
    do.call(navbarPage,
            c(
            title = 'test',
            lapply(
                  1:length(tabs),
                  function(i) {
                      tabPanel(
                          label[i], id=tabs[i],
                          fluidRow(
                              column(h4(label[i]),width=9),
                              column(img(src="logo.jpg", height="100pt", style=""), width=3)),
                          optionUI(i),
                          detailUI(i)
                      )
                  }
              )
            )
    )
)
```

#server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  lapply(
    1:length(tabs),
    function(i){
      optionServer(i)
      detailServer(i)
    }
  )
})
```

module code module/functmodul.R

```
optionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  a<-as.integer(id)
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns('testfx1')),
    lapply(1:nrow(option),function(d){ 
        getInput(a,d)
      })
  )
}

getInput<-function(id,d){
  ns<-NS(id)
  c<-opttab[id][,1][d] # c bestimmt die Art des Inputfelds (checkboxGroupI, radioButtons oder checkboxInput)
  switch(c,
         '1' = {checkboxGroupInput(ns(option$id[d]), option$label[d], optionset[[d]], selected = c(option$defval[d]), inline = TRUE)},
         '2' = {radioButtons(ns(option$id[d]), option$label[d], optionset[[d]], selected=option$defval[d], inline=TRUE)},
         '3' = {checkboxInput(ns(option$id[d]), option$label[d])},
         default = {}
  )
}

optionServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      for(z in 1:nrow(option)){
        c<-opttab[id][,1][z] 
       if (c!=0){
          optionSel[[paste0(option$id[z],tabs[id])]]<<-reactive({input[[option$id[z]]]})  #not working        
       }
      }
      output$testfx1<-renderPrint(input[[option$id[1]]]) #working
    }
  )    
}

detailUI<-function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns('testfx2'))
  )
}

detailServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$testfx2<-renderPrint(optionSel[[paste0(option$id[z],tabs[id])]]) #not working
    }
  )    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested, I found a solution that makes the program work even if it doesn't look very elegant.

I changed module/functmodul.R // optionServer as follows

```
 optionServer <- function(id) {
      moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
          a<-as.numeric(id)
          opt1<-reactive({input[[option$id[1]]]})
          opt2<-reactive({input[[option$id[2]]]})
          opt3<-reactive({input[[option$id[3]]]})
          opt4<-reactive({input[[option$id[4]]]})
          return(
            list(
              opt1,
              opt2,
              opt3,
              opt4
            )
          )
        }
      )    
    }
```

and then I got in Server.R

```
optionSel<-optionServer(i)
```

instead of the function call only...
so I can use optionSel[[1]], optionSel[[2]],...,optionSel[[5]] in server.R to call the return values